# Spring <util:map> shorthand as a bean property?

Tags: spring

I've searched quite a bit but haven't found an example or statement about this.

Is it possible to use the Spring (4.3 at this point) XML [`<util:map>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-map) shorthand to assign a `property` within a `bean`?

Specifically, I'd like to simplify/shorten this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="properties" value-ref="properties"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: xml wise that looks pretty short!

Comment: Perhaps :-) But if I can do what I'd like, it'd be even shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xml-wise that looks about as terse as it's going to get! The DTD doesn't support anything else.

Since you need refs, nothing inline is going to be any shorter either.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was trying to confirm - whether there was some Spring shorthand that would be allowed. But my experimenting hasn't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.Here is an example for you :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="attributes">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="key1" value="strValue" />   <!-- value is string -->
            <entry key="key2" value="1234" value-type="java.lang.Integer" /> <!-- Use value-type to explicitly specify the type -->
            <entry key="key3" value-ref="fooBean"/> <!-- Use value-ref to reference to other bean -->
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: That's not any shorter, though :-) I was hoping for something that could replace the `<bean>` or `<property>` entirely with `<util:map>`

Comment: How short do you want :-) ? `<util:map>` is used to define a bean which the type is Map and using it  you already don't need to use `<bean/>` for that  Map. Also a map only has key and value , so it is nothing to do with `<property>` .....

Answer (score 1):

Shortest I've found is this, which is 2-3 lines shorter, depending on formatting. And assuming you already have the necessary namespaces defined:

```
<util:map id="attributes">
    <entry key="properties" value-ref="properties"/>
</util:map>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter"
      p:attributes-ref="attributes"/>
```

But arguably not worth the additional indirection and (IMO) lower readability.